# ODE solver in F90

Tags: fortran, solver, ode

I decided to write my own solver (RK4th order) in F90 for a NPZD box model. It seems to run fine for the first 120 time steps (timestep = 1 day) and then it grows unrealistically. I reduced the time step and have the same problem. At this point I'm wondering how can I make stable the solver. Or if a better solution is to use one of the ODEPACK, which I'm not sure how to properly use. I would like to keep the timestep = 1 day, and also would like to learn how to make it stable without reducing the time step.
I am actually rewriting in Fortran a code done already in python (for technical reasons we need it in Fortran now) my college runs it without problems, but uses the available ODEs from python. In this same forum someone suggested (to someone else) to write her own solver in fortran, therefore I thought I can do that as well.

Below are the module of the solver and the main program:

```
subroutine solver(stateSim1E)
 type(ModelState) :: stateSim1E,stateSim1E1
type(ModelState) :: stateSim1E2,stateSim1E3,stateSim1E4

stateSim1E1 = dModelState(stateSim1E) !k1
!!$
stateSim1E2 = stateSim1E + 0.5*DTS*stateSim1E1 !cc1 K2
stateSim1E2 = dModelState(stateSim1E2)     

stateSim1E3 = stateSim1E + 0.5*DTS*(stateSim1E2)!k3
stateSim1E3 = dModelState(stateSim1E3) 

stateSim1E4 = stateSim1E + DTS*(stateSim1E3)!k4
stateSim1E4 = dModelState(stateSim1E4) 

stateSim1E = stateSim1E + (DTS/6)*(stateSim1E1 + 2._RK*(stateSim1E2 + stateSim1E3) +stateSim1E4)

end subroutine solver
```

main program

```
program main_npzdsv
use iso_fortran_env
use NumericKinds
use ModelState_class_npzdsv  
  integer :: i, outFileID,ti
  type(ModelState) :: stateSim1E, statePerturbation !,stateSim1E1

   !initial conditions
   stateSim1E = ModelState(N=N0,P=P0,Z=Z0,D=D0,S = s_mean0, V = s_var0)     


ti = 0 
do i = 1, NO_T_STEP
   ti = i     
   call getindex(ti)
   call solver(stateSim1E)
   print*,'new', index, stateSim1E

   if( mod(i-1, OUTPUT_FREQUENCY) == 0 ) then
      write(outFileID,'(i4)')index
      write(outFileID, '(18('// RK_FMT // ', 1x))') stateSim1E%getCurrModelState()
 end if
 end do
 close(outFileID) ! Clean-up for output
 close(outFileID2) ! Clean-up for output


end program main_npzdsv
```

!

Comment: Stability of an ODE solver is a *very* complex subject. It's likely your maximum allowable timestep is too small to be tractable. I recommend you look into other methods. Have you looked into an implicit formulation? We can't really help you with the choice of solution method here.

Comment: Are you sure your solver is right?  You are doing `stateSim1E = stateSim1E + (DTS/6)*(stateSim1E1 ...`, using the same term `stateSim1E` as both y_n and k_1, which (i think) is only right if f(t_n, y_n) = y_n.

Comment: Does this "NPZD" model mean some marine ecosystem model for nutrients (N), phytoplankton (P), zooplankton (Z) and detritus (D)? Also, is the ODE so-called a "stiff" one? If so, adaptive time-step integrators may be useful. Also I guess this question might be more suited to Computational Science forum http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comments, since its not so strait forwards the answer, I decided to decrease the time step to have some stability and now is working better. I will definitively try to look to and adaptive time-step integrator, I also think would be more useful.

Comment: This article might include some related references -- "Rosenbrock methods in biogeochemical modelling - A comparison to Runge-Kutta methods and modified Patankar schemes"  http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011OcMod..37..112S  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1463500311000102

Comment: did the answer below help solving your problem? If it helped, please accept it to help those who have similar problem. If it did not help, please let me know so that I can delete it to save people from wasting their time looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

The first think to check is the [CFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition). Explicit methods sometime require very small time step as opposed to implicit methods that are sometime unconditionally stable.
Checking the CFL can actually be tricky for problems where the velocity evolves in time. It is very challenging for spinup problem.  By spinup, I mean when you want to run a long time simulation from very small perturbation to get to a realistic state. For example simulating the water circulation in a gulf from rest. The initial transient can generate very high velocity that makes it very difficult to satisfy the CFL and break the system.

If you absolutely want your time step of at least one day, you will possibly need to increase your step in space. Another simple approach is to read the doc of the toolbox used in python to get information about the underlying method.

(This is not the solution, it is an indication that is too long to be put as comment)